# How to hide song names on Jplayer playlist

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

I implemented the **jplayer** playlist, because it moves to next song when first one gets finished.

But the thing is, I don't want song names to be displayed on my page.

If I remove this piece of code:

```
<div class="jp-playlist">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The player won't play automatically, it needs to go to 2nd song and then works properly.
I want it to play automatically when page loads, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after your jplayer is initialized, instead remove, why don"t you just hide this like that :

```
$('.jp-playlist').hide();
```